# mysql cant start in xampp

Tags: mysql

this is what happens when i run mysql

```
22.33.16  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.

22.33.16  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 

22.33.16  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

22.33.16  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check

22.33.16  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues

22.33.16  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this

22.33.16  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums

22.33.19  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...

22.33.19  [mysql]   Status change detected: running

22.33.20  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped

22.33.20  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.

22.33.20  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 

22.33.20  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

22.33.21  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check

22.33.21  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues

22.33.21  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this

22.33.21  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

can anybody tell me, what should i do to fix this problem?

Comment: Try https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com

Comment: please unintall your xampp server & remove folder from root directory & again install it.

Comment: The error log gives you pretty good idea where to start. Have you checked anything on that list?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the default port 3306 that MySQL use is in use from another program. Check that first. Try with `netstat -ab` in command prompt to see which application use this port.

Another suggestion is if you have firewall that is blocking MySQL...